# Dynamic XML code generation in C++

Tags: c++, xml, code-generation

I would like to transform some C++ objects of classes of my own into XML code. I guess there are several libraries which provide C++ to XML-mapping, but I would like to keep the library overhead simple and craft something of my own.

What would be an appropriate approach to generate XML building? In Java there are annotations which could be use to dynamaically generate the XML. Maybe the template mechanism?

I am using TinyXML so far. I really enjoy using it.

Here is an example, which I would like to be generated:

```
std::string XMLBuilder::buildThreadInformation(vector<threadinfo> threadinfos) {
TiXmlDocument document;
TiXmlDeclaration *declaration = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "", "");

TiXmlElement *messageWrapElement = new TiXmlElement("message");
TiXmlElement *threadsElement = new TiXmlElement("threads");
messageWrapElement->LinkEndChild(threadsElement);

std::string numberString;
for (vector<threadinfo>::const_iterator it = threadinfos.begin(); it
        != threadinfos.end(); ++it) {
    TiXmlElement *threadElement = new TiXmlElement("thread");
    threadsElement->LinkEndChild(threadElement);

    TiXmlElement *threadNumberElement = new TiXmlElement("number");
    threadElement->LinkEndChild(threadNumberElement);

    numberString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>((*it).thread_number);
    TiXmlText *threadNumber = new TiXmlText(numberString.c_str());
    threadNumberElement->LinkEndChild(threadNumber);

    TiXmlElement *threadNameElement = new TiXmlElement("name");
    threadElement->LinkEndChild(threadNameElement);

    TiXmlText *threadName = new TiXmlText((*it).name.c_str());
    threadNameElement->LinkEndChild(threadName);
}

document.LinkEndChild(declaration);
document.LinkEndChild(messageWrapElement);

TiXmlPrinter printer;
document.Accept(&printer);

std::string result = printer.CStr();

return result;
```

}

The class threadinfo would consist of int number and std::string name.

Comment: Would you further explain your problem and provide a small example of what you would like to do? It's not clear to me from your question if you are trying to serialize objects to xml, write your own declarative XML language like XAML, or something else entirely.

Comment: @Nathanael: You are right. I added an example, I hope it is small enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) is also pretty easy to use and can create dynamic xml for you.